# Pasar de PostgreSQL a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql-9.3

Lo que sucede es que tengo un script de PostgreSQL y necesito pasarlo a SQL Server. ¿Alguien conoce una herramienta que sea efectiva?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un Script o la base de DB (Data and Schema)???.

Cualquiera que sea el caso existe dos opciones:
1 - La "Free", pero mas trabajo. 
2 - La simple y fácil pero costosa $$.

1 -Para la primera opción no es difícil solo que cuesta mas trabajo hacerla.
Ahora bien si tienes los drivers correctos en tu MS-SQLServer para soporte de Postgrest(ODBC) puedes hacer un export/import data via wizard para copiar la  información.
Si tu script es muy grande a nivel de data puede que te encuentre algunas incongruencias por eso de tener un gran números de rows, por lo cual tendrías que pasar a hacer simples  insert segmentados.

2 - Existe herramientas de pago que te exportan  tu full Schema (table data, indexes, foreign keys, constraints pero sin data) [Full Export Schem Export](https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert), pero una vez que tengas tu DB definida solo es cuestión de hacer un simple txt import de la data.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me puedes explicar un poco mas la opcion free por favor?.

Comment: OK, te diré paso por paso todo lo que tienes que hacer pero primero necesito que aterrices un poco la pregunta ya que es un poco ambigua.

Un ejemplo que puede ayudar es mostrando un fragmento de tu Script.sql  o  talvez aclarar si tienes instalado la base de datos en Servidor PostgresSQL y por otro lado Un server de MS-SQLServer.

osea tienes que ser mas especifico con tus preguntas. Recuerda que: Preguntas genericas  reciben Respuestas Genericas.